# Update/Synchronize App Maker datasource fields after Cloud SQL Schema update?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have an app that includes a datasource created from an existing Cloud SQL table.  A column has since been added to the Cloud SQL table (outside of App Maker).

How do I get the App Maker datasource to reflect the new table schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to **Settings -> Database** and click `Check` button:
[image: Database Settings]

App Maker will show you a dialog with multiple choices. You can opt to import changes from database:
[image: Database synchronization options]

In other words, App Maker supports both Database First and *kinda* Code First development approaches.

Comment: Do I not have the Database Menu because I was using a Spreadsheet and I think it's called Google Drives Table?

Comment: BTW this AppMaker is pretty cool.  I'm impressed with all of the new script I've learned today.  That comes a surprise for a tool that's advertised as a low coding tool.  It kind of reminds me of Borland C++ from years past

Comment: Fantastic!  I was anticipating having to settle for a workaround, but I'm happy to see that I was just unaware of that feature.  Thanks Pavel, for all of the answers you continue to provide to this community.

Comment: @Cooper - The database settings only apply to Cloud SQL datasources (at this time), so you wouldn't see these settings for either Sheets or Google Drive tables.